# Socrata callback url issue

Tags: socrata

I am currently inplementing socrata oauth2 for accessing private information.call back url is not accepting localhost path example:http://localhost:8080/callback.

Let me know is there any way to use redirect url?

Answer (score 0):

The callback relies on that URL being public, but you can use a service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to relay your requests and give you a public URL for development. I've had a lot of success with that in the past.